# Dynamic programming and probability - list of problems

Tags: dynamic-programming, probability-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

Does anyone have a list of problems where you have to combine dynamic programming  with probability?

Comment: I'm not sure this site is the best place to ask for learning materials of this sort.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Hm I thought on this site are mainly computer science students so I assumed that someone could maybe provide me certain resources...

Answer (score 1):

You can use search on this site to find some examples: https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdynamic-programming%5D+probability